# React redux validating props from uploaded json file

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to create a simple user interface where it should be possible to upload a json file, and then it will get checked if certain keys are in it. So what happens in my code, is that when someone uploads a json file, an action is dispatched. In this action I read the file, and check for certain keys, if a key is not present in the file uploaded, I push it to an array. My problem is, that something goes wrong when the state is returned, because the missingProps aren't getting set correctly in the state.

```
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const missingProps = [];
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        const result = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
        // const formatted = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);

        function checkProperties(property, object) {
            property in object ? console.log('Child detected') : missingProps.push(property);
        }
        checkProperties('keyExists', result);
        checkProperties('keyNotExist', result);
    }
    reader.readAsText(acceptedFiles[0]);

    return {
        type: UploadActionTypes.UPLOAD_JSON,
        json: acceptedFiles[0],
        missingProps: missingProps
    };
```

My immiediate thought is that because its a callback function, the state is returned before the function is evaluated. Also when I check the console, it says that missingProps in the next state is an Array(0), but if I open up the state object, I can see that it in fact has a key.

I've been playing around with thunk middleware and promises for the past 3 hours, but I can't seem to get it to work.
A link to the code can be found here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/50r2vwmx1n

If you prefer looking at the raw code, I've pasted it below.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import UploadReducer from './reducers/upload';
import UploadContainer from './containers/UploadContainer';

import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware";

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, createLogger());

const store = createStore(UploadReducer, middleware);

store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log("Store changed", store.getState());
})

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <UploadContainer />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

**UploadContainer**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as UploadActionCreators from '../actions/upload';
import Upload from '../components/Upload';

class UploadContainer extends Component {

    render() {
        const { dispatch, json, missingProps } = this.props;
        const uploadJson = bindActionCreators(UploadActionCreators.uploadJson, dispatch);

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="App-header">
                    <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
                </div>
                <Upload onDrop={uploadJson} json={this.props.json}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (
    {
        json: state.json,
        missingProps: state.missingProps
    }
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UploadContainer);
```

**UploadComponent**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';

const Upload = props => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Hello React!</h1>
            <Dropzone onDrop={props.onDrop}>
                {props.json ? props.json.name : "Drop some json"}
            </Dropzone>
            <p>Missing properties:</p>
                {props.missingProps ? props.missingProps.map(prop => <li>{prop}</li>) : ''}
            <ul>
            </ul>

        </div>
    )
}

Upload.propTypes = {
    onDrop: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Upload;
```

**UploadActionType**

```
export const UPLOAD_JSON = 'upload/UPLOAD_JSON';
```

**UploadAction**

```
import * as UploadActionTypes from '../actiontypes/upload';

// export const uploadJson = (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {
//     return {
//         type: UploadActionTypes.UPLOAD_JSON,
//         acceptedFiles,
//         rejectedFiles
//     };
// };

export const uploadJson = (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const missingProps = [];
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        const result = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
        // const formatted = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);

        function checkProperties(property, object) {
            property in object ? console.log('Child detected') : missingProps.push(property);
        }
        checkProperties('keyExists', result);
        checkProperties('keyNotExist', result);
    }
    reader.readAsText(acceptedFiles[0]);

    return {
        type: UploadActionTypes.UPLOAD_JSON,
        json: acceptedFiles[0],
        missingProps: missingProps
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading a file is asynchronous. But your action creator is executed and instantly returns.

`{
    type: UploadActionTypes.UPLOAD_JSON,
    json: acceptedFiles[0],
    missingProps: missingProps
 };`

to the store. But missingProps was not filled yet. You need to use redux-thunk.

```
export const uploadJson = (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => (dispatch) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const missingProps = [];
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        const result = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
        // const formatted = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);

        function checkProperties(property, object) {
            property in object ? console.log('Child detected') : missingProps.push(property);
        }
        checkProperties('keyExists', result);
        checkProperties('keyNotExist', result);
        dispatch({
            type: UploadActionTypes.UPLOAD_JSON,
            json: acceptedFiles[0],
            missingProps
        })
    }
    reader.readAsText(acceptedFiles[0]);
```

};

By the way, your console.log in reducer should look like this `console.log("missing properties:", action.missingProps);`

It should be hinted by the fact that it outputs `undefined` instead of `[]`